# Masstransit publish message to multiple Queues by single exchange

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, message-queue, masstransit

i write simple project with  by using #Masstransit and #RabbitMq .
I wanna to publish some messages to #RabbitMq bus and use single Exchange to Route my message into suitable Queues (My Mean to use #Direct Type of #Exchange).
on the other side I wrote Multiple #IConsumers to Subscribe specific queue.
but the problem is the consumer was not specified and catch all messages from all Type.
so please tell what I was wrong.

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
    x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
    
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("127.0.0.1", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("admin");
            h.Password("123@321");
        });
        cfg.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(
            new EnvironmentNameFormatter(cfg.MessageTopology.EntityNameFormatter));
        cfg.Publish<HelloContract>(cfgt =>
        {
            cfgt.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
            cfgt.Durable = false;
            var flightTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FlightServiceTypeEnum));

            foreach (var flightType in flightTypes)
            {
                cfgt.BindQueue($"{HelloContract.ContractModelFullName}",
                    $"{HelloContract.ContractModelFullName}-{flightType}",
                    (cf) =>
                    {
                        cf.RoutingKey = $"{flightType}";
                        cf.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                        cf.Durable = false;
                    }
                );
            }
        });


        var exchangeName = HelloContract.ContractModelFullName;
        var queueName = $"{exchangeName}-{FlightServiceTypeEnum.Sepehr}";

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{exchangeName}-{FlightServiceTypeEnum.Sepehr}",
            e =>
            {
                 e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                e.Durable = false;
                e.ConfigureConsumer<SepehrHelloWorldConsumer>(context);

                e.Bind(exchangeName,
                    y =>
                    {
                        y.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                        y.RoutingKey = $"{FlightServiceTypeEnum.Sepehr}";
                        y.Durable = false;
                    });
            });

        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint($"{exchangeName}-{FlightServiceTypeEnum.IranAir}",
            e =>
            {
                e.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
                e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                e.Durable = false;
                e.ConfigureConsumer<IranAirHelloWorldConsumer>(context);
                e.Bind(exchangeName,
                    y =>
                    {
                        y.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Direct;
                        y.RoutingKey = $"{FlightServiceTypeEnum.IranAir}";
                        y.Durable = false;
                    });
            });
        
    });
});
```

```
public class SepehrHelloWorldConsumer : IConsumer<HelloContract>
{
    private readonly ILogger<SepehrHelloWorldConsumer> _logger;
    

    public SepehrHelloWorldConsumer(ILogger<SepehrHelloWorldConsumer> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<HelloContract> context)
    {
        
        _logger.LogInformation("---Sepehr--- {MessageName} {DateTime},RoutingKey:{routing-key}", context.Message.Name, DateTime.Now,context.RoutingKey());
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IBus _bus;

    private Array flightTypes;

    public Worker(IBus bus)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        flightTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(FlightServiceTypeEnum));
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                var random = new Random();
                var flightServiceType = (FlightServiceTypeEnum)flightTypes.GetValue(random.Next(flightTypes.Length));

                var helloContract = new HelloContract()
                    { Name = $"{flightServiceType}", FlightServiceTypeEnum = flightServiceType };
                await _bus.Publish(helloContract, stoppingToken);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace SimpleRabbitApp.Contracts;

public record HelloContract
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public FlightServiceTypeEnum FlightServiceTypeEnum { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    public static string ContractModelFullName => $"{typeof(HelloContract).Namespace}:{nameof(HelloContract)}";
}

public enum FlightServiceTypeEnum
{
    Sepehr,
    IranAir,
    Nira,
    Sepehran
}
```

want to solve my problem